# PRESTO MAP_FROM_ENTRIES AND CROSS JOIN UNNEST

Tags: sql, presto

I have two queries which I Union and then use crossjoin unnest. The main purpose is I want to get the output that is item_name, item_value in horizontal table rather than vertical

```
WITH base AS(
SELECT ds,MAP_FROM_ENTRIES(ARRAY [('X',COUNT_IF(X != 0)),('y',SUM(Y))]) AS metrics_map
FROM table1

UNION ALL

SELECT ds,MAP_FROM_ENTRIES( ARRAY [('A',COUNT_IF(A != 0)),('b',SUM(B))]) AS metrics_map
FROM table2
)

SELECT ds,metric_name,metric_value from base cross join unnest(metrics_map) AS t(metric_name, metric_value)
```

The output should be ds,metric_name,metric_value with values in metric_name as X,y,A,B but i get values only as A,B. Can anyone help me to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip `MAP_FROM_ENTRIES` and use default row fields names for your entries:

```sql
WITH dataset AS (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES   
        (1, ARRAY [('X', 1),('y',2)]),
        (2, ARRAY [('A', 3),('B',4)])
 ) AS t (ds, metrics_array))

SELECT ds, metric.field0 as metric_name, metric.field1 as metric_value
FROM dataset 
cross join unnest(metrics_array) as t(metric)
```

And possibly use `transform` to give more meaningful names:

```sql
WITH dataset AS (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES   
        (1, ARRAY [('X', 1), ('y',2)]),
        (2, ARRAY [('A', 3),('B',4)])
 ) AS t (ds, metrics_array))

SELECT ds, metric.metric_name, metric.metric_value
FROM (
  SELECT ds, transform(metrics_array, r -> CAST(r as ROW(metric_name VARCHAR, metric_value DOUBLE))) as metrics_array
  FROM dataset
  ) 
cross join unnest(metrics_array) as t(metric)
```

Output:

| ds | metric_name | metric_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | X | 1.0 |
| 1 | y | 2.0 |
| 2 | A | 3.0 |
| 2 | B | 4.0 |